# How do I render my basic signup/login forms on the page using AJAX rather than re-directing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

Maybe I've just been staring at this too long, but I have a basic sign-up and log-in form that I built, and want to just render them on the same page in a div rather than redirecting to a new page.

here's my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thanks for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

end
```

with a similar one for session

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
  end

end
```

and here is the relevant part of the view of the one-page app

```
<div id="user">
  <% if current_user %>
    Logged in as <%= current_user.email %>.
    <%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, remote: true, disable_with: "Goodbye!", :class => "logout_a" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign Up", signup_path, remote: true, disable_with: "Welcome!", :class => "signup_a" %> or
    <%= link_to "Log In", login_path, remote: true, disable_with: "Welcome Back!", :class => "login_a" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="render_here">
</div>
```

with class "render_here" being where I want to render the forms.

I've tried rendering a partial within the link_to specification, using .js.erb files in my view, and a couple of other ideas I got by googling the problem, but I think I'm overcomplicating things and missing an easy solution for AJAXifying the signup and login process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`respond_with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
  def new
    @user = User.new
    respond_with @user
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks for signing up!"
    end
    respond_with @user
  end

end
```

`respond_with` is smart about the formats, if request comes in html. it will respond with html respond. if request comes in `json` i.e via ajax. `respond_with` would send an json response

Answer (score 0):

If it is static page,You can use

```
 <%=  render :partial => "login_form"%>
```

[RoR Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) supplies good info on that. login_form must be saved as "_login_form.erb"

If it is dynamic page, you can send a ajax request when the link clicks and render a html form from that request and fill the div, from response data.